# Can't see the NFS shared directory in Vagrant

Tags: ruby, vagrant, nfs

I try to create an `NFS` share directory in the vagrant box, but for some reasons I can not see the shared directory when I login to the box via ssh.

This is my Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise32"
   config.vm.synced_folder "./shared", "/st/data", :nfs => true
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
end
```

Vagrant reload output:

```
vagrant reload
==> default: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
==> default: Checking if box 'hashicorp/precise32' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
GuestAdditions 5.0.6 running --- OK.
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Exporting NFS shared folders...
==> default: Preparing to edit /etc/exports. Administrator privileges will be required...
==> default: Mounting NFS shared folders...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => /Users/stk/Documents/vagrant
==> default: Check for insecure vagrant key: OK (not present)
==> default: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
==> default: flag to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.
```

After `vagrant ssh` I can't see any nfs directory.

```
vagrant -v
Vagrant 1.7.4
```

OSX:

`10.10.3`

I tried most of the solutions mentioned [here](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/3341), but still no luck.

Comment: weird, output looks correct - can you open VirtualBox and for the vm's shared folder setting check if there is an error highlighted ?

Comment: No, there is no error highlight in VirtualBox

Comment: and `cd /st/data` from the VM does not lead anything ?

Comment: No it says directory is not exist; I tried to create the dir manually and then reload but still the same.

Comment: the same - you mean like the directory does not exists ?  its been deleted ? maybe run with `vagrant up --debug` to see if there's anything interesting happening when it mounts the folder